# How to disable proactive detection emails in Azure RM template

Tags: azure-application-insights

We have begun creating our AppInsights resources via an AzureRM template.  But there does not appear to be a way to disable the "Email detections to co-admins" option, so we still have to manually navigate through the portal to disable this option.

As a co-admin with approximately 30 AI resources now (multiple environments), the daily emails are becoming painful.

I would like to know how to turn off this option in a script (preferably in the template json file).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Application Insights doesn't support this action through PowerShell; it is on the product backlog for a future release.